# XSLT with database querying

Tags: java, xslt, xquery

I've been doing XML transformation for a while in my Java application and I'm still not clear what the options are and what the best option is to read records from a database and insert it in my transformed output file.

What I've been doing so far is querying an Oracle database with xQuery that gave me a nodeset as a result. I then passed this result as a parameter to the transformer and queried that parameter during the transformation to insert data into the appropriate nodes.

Is this the best way of doing it though? My base language again is Java. What would be the other options to get the same result?

Also I think it's worth mentioning that most of the times the db query is based on the content of the source XML file.

Thanks

Comment: @L4zl0w: Without complete use case this kind of design question is subjective. Depending on the transformation complexity, it might be better to use only XQuery.

Comment: @Alejandro: Unfortunately I don't have the specifics yet, so I'm trying to understand my options. When you refer to xQuery, do you mean to run an xQuery and feed the result to the transformer as a parameter? Thanks!

Comment: What concerns you with the current design? To me it looks OK and normal.

Comment: @road to yamburg: 'My only concern is that it doesn't work yet.:) I'm having issues with passing the result set in a proper format to the transformer so I can actually access it. And the other thing is, I have to parse the xml first and then build the xquery that gives me several rows, while if I do it inside the transformer I can just form a query each time I need it during transformation.

Comment: @L4zl0w: I meant to run only one XQuery for the complete task.

Comment: @Alejandro: Would this still work if I'm transforming an XML file from one format to another with a stylesheet at the same time? So basically I have two source, an XML document and database query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Saxon SQL extensions, in particular at [**`<sql:query>`**](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sql-extension/query.xml) extension element?

Comment: thanks I think I need something like this. Seems like I have two options: XQuery which I'm still not sure how to access SQL from it, and Saxon SQL extension.

Comment: Seems like there is also a sql extension to Xalan! http://xml.apache.org/xalan/sql

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to instantiate a Java object in your XSLT script;

```
    <!-- Connection to the data provider. -->
    <xsl:variable name="provider" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
        select="java:my.sample.DataProvider.getInstance()" />
```

Using it to provide the data later on in the script:

```
    <xsl:template match="node">
        <xsl:variable name="mydata" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
                    select="java:getdata($provider,  string(@attr))" />
```

This would call the method `getData(String)` on the object created by the static `getInstance()` method on your `my.sample.DataProvider` class.

You can use a setup like this to get values from a cache (for instance the query results you try to pass as parameter in your current setup), or to execute queries while transform is executed (preventing queries to data that is not visited by the transform.)

Comment: While it is an interesting mental exercise, I wouldn't advise anything like this to be actually used. A mix of concerns in its finest.

Comment: @road to yamburg: could you please elaborate the concerns? can you think of a better solution? thanks!

Comment: Mix of concerns: database access and logic in one piece of code (XSLT). Proper way is to get data from database in one place, then process them in another place paying no attention where they came from. Makes changes easier (decoupling), makes testing easier (mocks), and so on. One can do a lot of things within XSLT, as it is a powerful language, but if it can be done doesn't mean it should be done.

Comment: I agree with @road that separation of concerns is an important issue and that you should not use a construct like this to access data to be transformed. I do also believe however that this is a valid approach for these situations where multiple data sources are used to render primary XML data. (Better than to preprocess your XML to determine which data you should offer via parameters - which duplicates your logic.) The access to the data is decoupled by use of a factory pattern. The provider object should offer an abstraction for data access, you should not use it as a DB function.